# Datatables responsive and first column fixed width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable. The table displayed as a responsive one.
But the first column is to big, so on a big screen only saw the first column.
Now a found the columnDefs to set the width of the columns. Great that goes, but not with the responsive. 
Had anyone a solutuion for combination of fixed width and responsive?

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $('#tablePager').DataTable( {
                    responsive: true,
                    paging: false,

                    /*columnDefs: [
                        { "width": "20%" }
                      ]*/
                    colReorder: {
                        reorderCallback: function () {
                            console.log( 'callback' );
                        }
                    }
                } );

            } );
```

Comment: Can you include any code or working example, because it is very difficult for us to visualize your problem without looking at the html & CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#tablePager').DataTable( {
                responsive: true,
                paging: false,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
                ]
                colReorder: {
                    reorderCallback: function () {
                        console.log( 'callback' );
                    }
                }
            } );

        } );
```

Use target to specify the column index.